# pig latin-like program - issues with vowels

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that has two rules:
1. If the first character of the word is a vowel, then move it to the end of the word.
2. If the first character of the word is a consonant, then move it to the end of the word and append 'ae'.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a sentence: ");
        String english = scanner.nextLine();
        String piggy = piggyEnglish(english);
        System.out.print("Translated: " + piggy);
    }
     private static String piggyEnglish(String s) {
            String piggy = "";
            int i = 0;
            while (i<s.length()) {

              while (i<s.length() && !isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {
                piggy = piggy + s.charAt(i);
                i++;
              }

              if (i>=s.length()) break;

              int begin = i;
              while (i<s.length() && isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {
                i++;
              }

              int end = i;
              piggy = piggy + piggyWord(s.substring(begin, end));
            }
            return piggy;
          }

     private static boolean beginsWithVowel(String word){
              String vowels = "aeiou";
              char letter = word.charAt(0);
              return (vowels.indexOf(letter) != -1);
              }

     private static boolean isLetter(char c) {
        return ( (c >='A' && c <='Z') || (c >='a' && c <='z') );
      }

    private static String piggyWord(String word) {
            int split = firstVowel(word);
            if(beginsWithVowel(word)) {
                return word.substring(split) + word.substring(0, split);
            } else {
            return word.substring(split) + word.substring(0, split)+"ae";
            }
    }       

    private static int firstVowel(String word) {
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
          if (word.charAt(i)=='a' || word.charAt(i)=='e' ||
              word.charAt(i)=='i' || word.charAt(i)=='o' ||
              word.charAt(i)=='u')
            return i;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The following is the expected output:

```
Please enter a sentence: today is a beautiful day 
Translated: odaytae si a eautifulbae aydae
```

However, this is what I'm getting:

```
Please enter a sentence: today is a beautiful day
Translated: odaytae is a eautifulbae aydae
```

Basically, it doesn't translate any words that start with a vowel. I think the problem stems from the piggyWord method, but I'm not certain. Can I get any pointers on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in the `piggyWord` function:

```
private static String piggyWord(String word) {
        int split = firstVowel(word);
        if(beginsWithVowel(word)) {
            return word.substring(split + 1) + word.substring(0, split + 1); //Since vowel is in 1st place, substring(0,0) returns empty string.
        } else {
        return word.substring(split) + word.substring(0, split)+"ae";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your rules, you don't need the method firstVowel() to get the index of the first vow in a word because you only need to know whether the first character in the word is a vow or not.

So simply change you piggyWord method to the following will solve your problem:

```
private static String piggyWord(String word) {
    if(beginsWithVowel(word)) {
        return word.substring(1) + word.substring(0, 1);
    } else {
        return word.substring(1) + word.substring(0, 1)+"ae";
    }
}
```

Or more simply:

```
private static String piggyWord(String word) {
    String result = word.substring(1) + word.substring(0, 1);
    return beginsWithVowel(word) ? result : result + "ae";
}
```

Because you always have to move the first character of a word to the end, the only thing is that whether you need to append an extra "ae" in the end or not.

Answer (score 0):

If only the first letter is concerned than in "firstVowel" you can return 1 if vowel is at first position.

```
private static int firstVowel(String word) {
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
      if (word.charAt(i)=='a' || word.charAt(i)=='e' ||
          word.charAt(i)=='i' || word.charAt(i)=='o' ||
          word.charAt(i)=='u')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```